# Understanding a proof about mapping properties of Klein's modular function $J$ (Apostol's "Modular Functions and Dirichlet Series in Number Theory")

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, proof-explanation, analytic-number-theory, modular-function

I'm studying Tom Apostol's "Modular Functions and Dirichlet Series in Number Theory", and there's one statement in Chapter 2 that I do not understand.

Let $R_\Gamma$ be the usual fundamental region for the modular group, and let $A = \{\tau \in R_\Gamma : \text{Re}(\tau) < 0\}$. Then Klein's modular function $J$ maps $A$ onto the upper-half plane $H$.

Apostol's proof involves showing that the three edges of $A$ are mapped onto $(-\infty, 0], [0, 1]$ and $[1, \infty)$ respectively, which I am fine with. Now comes the part I do not understand. He says that "As the boundary of $R_\Gamma$ is traversed counterclockwise the points inside $R_\Gamma$ lie on the left, hence the image points lie above the real axis in the image plane".

I am familiar with such arguments when applied using conformal maps, which are orientation-preserving, but $J$ is not conformal (since, for instance, it does not preserve the angles between the edges of the region $A$), so I don't see why the reasoning applies.

I have been able to cook up a more complicated proof by considering directly a point of the form $u + iv \in A$ for $-\frac{1}{2} < u < 0$, but I would like to understand Apostol's argument, as it seems much more elegant than my own.

Comment: $J$ is conformal inside the region as well as on the boundary except at two points, so it is orientation preserving (the Jacobian is non-negative after all)

Comment: @Conrad Is it obvious that $J$ is conformal? I can't find it in the book, and also haven't been able to find a proof online.

Comment: it is theorem 1.15 in the book (p 15) and it is not hard to prove from the definition as $g_2,g_3$ are given by locally uniformly convergent series in $\tau$, $\Delta=g_2^3-27g_3^2$ is analytic and non zero, so $J$ is same as a ratio of analytic functions with denominator never zero - note that $J$ gives a very easy proof of Picard's (big) theorem about entire functions omitting at most $1$ finite value because it is locally conformal except at two finite points, so a local inverse would send an entire function omitting two finite points to the upper plane hence to the disc hence bounded

Comment: meant $J$ locally conformal except at two finite values of course (each with infinite preimage through the modular group)

Comment: In my edition, theorem 1.15 just says that the functions are analytic in $H$. For it to be conformal, don't we have to show that the derivative is nonzero?

Comment: I see now the question - because $J$ is analytic and invariant, it can fail to be conformal at only countably many points inside a fundamental domain; then because $J$ is $1-1$ there, it follows it is conformal inside the fundamental domains (local expansion around interior critical points is not 1-1), so it can fail conformality only on the boundary and then it is easy to see that can happen only at the non-analytic points of the boundary regarded as a curve which are precisely two (finite) and there indeed it fails conformality having a triple zero and a double $1$ respectively